# Как получить google play services в jar формате?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-play

Где я могу получить google services в формате jar? Пытался загрузить через SDK Manager, переходил по пути указанном в других похожих вопросах, но самого jar нет. Можно их скачать где-то напрямую?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733844/download-google-play-services-jar

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло.